# Index.path not returning the correct index

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

So I am a beginner and just started learning swift. I am having an issue with an array and a tableView. Basically I have two arrays. One has all the names of fruits + vegetables while the other array has description of each. 
I have been able to display all the fruits in that array as a table. Now i want the correct description to appear when I press on a certain cell. So for eg, when I press Apple, i want a small description of it to show. 
I am using this function :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{

    myIndex = indexPath.row
    print(myIndex)

        }
```

and then I am using myIndex variable to store the index number of the selected item. Now just to test out, I am printing myindex and I am getting wrong index numbers for all. for the second item instead of 1 i am getting 2 and in other cases, it doesn't provide me the index of the first item and starts with second.

What am I doing wrong here. I plan to use this indexpath.row and display the description of the respective item.

Any help would be suffice.

Here is the code:

```
var list = ["Apple", "Oranges", "Mangoes"]
var detaillist = ["Red", "Orange is Orange", "Mangoes are yellow"]
var myIndex = 0


 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return(list.count)
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
    return(cell)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
    {
        list.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        myTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{

    myIndex = indexPath.row
    print(myIndex)

        }
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: didDeselectRowAt change to didselectRowAt.

Comment: Consider to avoid three (beginner) mistakes: **1) Don't use multiple arrays as data source** Your code will crash at some point after deleting only the item in `list` but not in `detailList`. Use a custom struct **2) Don't declare the data source array outside the class** This is bad habit and defeats data encapsulation. **3) Don't create cells with the designated initializer, reuse them**. (`tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier....`)

Comment: @vadian Thanks so much! Just started Swift earlier today. Will make sure to implement the above tips in the next code. :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your selection function to-:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
         didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
}
```